# Windows is setting a 1GBit connection down to 100mbit

Tags: networking, windows-10, drivers, network-adapter, throttling

My current network should support wired 1Gbit connection. It used to be 1Gbit on my PC, but some time ago Windows started to see it as 100mbit. After trying several things, I am 100% it is an OS issue.

Things I've tried so far:

- fiddled with device settings, set up speed to 1Gbit full-duplex, without downgrading connection speed, disabled Gigabit Lite - *didn't help*
- bought new Cat6 cable, to rule out bad cable - *didn't help*
- tried upgrading NIC drivers - *didn't help*
- disabled hibernation in Windows - *didn't help*
- bought an USB3.0 NIC, to rule out faulty card - *didn't help*
- set up another PC, connected both old and new cables - *second PC detects as 1Gbit on both cables*
- tried using Linux Live distro on main PC - *detects as 1Gbit on both cables and NICs*

This suggests it is a Windows installation issue, but I'd very much like to avoid reinstalling Windows. Is there anything else I could try out?

- on-board NIC is Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- driver is 10.10.714.2016, unsure what it was before updating
- second PC has driver version 9.1.410.2015. I'm unsure if reverting to that version could help, tried doing so but failed - Realtek drivers are pain to install
- main PC winver is 1909 (build 18363.592), auto-update enabled and OS is up to date
- second PC winver is 1903 (build 18362.592), auto-update enabled

Comment: FYI Cat5 is enough for GigaLan.

Comment: Does your configuration look like this for the adapter settings?

Auto Disable Gigabit > Disable

Green Ethernet > Disable

Energy Efficient Ethernet > Disable

Comment: @SQLTemp all that you mentioned are `Disabled`. Speed/duplex is `1.0 Gbps Full Duplex`. WOL is `Not Speed Down`. Power Plan is `High Efficiency`. Gigabit Lite is also `Disabled`.

Comment: @jw_ well aware of that, but decided to go for Cat6 anyway, just in case my Windows decided it's not enough; sometimes I think all computers are actually quantum and moody at times.

Comment: @jw_ There's no point to buying CAT5 when CAT6 is only [~$2 more](https://www.monoprice.com/category/cables/networking-patch-cables) per 100ft, even more so when one considers CAT5 is obsolete.

Comment: @JW0914 Wiki mention CAT5 is obsoleted by CAT5e, not CAT6. If the price is like that then it is obsoleted by CAT6, but the fact may be the CAT6/CAT7 cable you can buy is indeed CAT5e since for shorter length like 5m lower quanlity cable can be used too. Competition may make home <10m real CAT6 cable not easy to find.

Comment: @jw_ My point is if you're going to invest in something, invest in something that's still going to be useful 10yrs down the road.  Businesses have a use for CAT5e over CAT6, consumers don't... it's also simpler for a consumer to stick to one or the other standards because the wiring/pinout is different, and since consumers will already be using CAT6 in their homes, it makes no sense to buy CAT5e, especially when it's a difference of mere cents between the two cable types.  _(A general FYI, the only electronics I'm aware of that still even come with CAT5e pre-packaged are modems and printers.)_

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I thought disabling "Power Saving Mode" worked for me, for about 48 hours, and then it went back to 100mbps

Answer (score 3):

### Reviewing & Confirming what hasn't solved the problem yet

You may want to check the settings on your router as I've heard that even if you set the adapter settings to full duplex, if the router is set to automatic, it may sometimes cause undesirable effects.

Otherwise, I've noted you've mentioned fiddling with these settings (as well as as mentioned in the comments) *just to confirm in case others coming to this page miss what to try for themselves*:

- **Speed & Duplex** ("set up speed to 1Gbit full-duplex, without downgrading connection speed") *Since you've set it on your adapter to 1.0 Gbps Full Duplex, you may want to try changing it back to Auto Negotiation if after doing the other Settings listed still doesn't help and in case your router is set to automatic.*
- **Gigabit Lite** ("disabled Gigabit Lite") - *Leave disabled*
- **WOL & Shutdown Link Speed** ("...is Not Speed Down") *This shouldn't effect anything as it's a Wake on Lan setting for when your computer is off or in standby, set however you want.*
- Windows **Power Plan** is *High Efficiency*. - *You may want to try setting it to **High performance** instead or open advanced and change the specific network adapter adapter setting within your preferred power plan*
- And you confirmed that **Auto Disable Gigabit**, **Green Ethernet**, **Energy Efficient Ethernet** are all set to *disabled* as SQLTemp already mentioned.

### Suggested Solutions

*Now here are some other steps you can try:*

- The advanced setting for **Jumbo Frame** set to *disabled*.
- In the NIC **Properties** windows under the **Power Management** tab, ensure that "*Allow the  computer to turn off this device to save power*" is *unchecked*. You may also want to go one step further and check device manager, organize it by connection, and ensure none of the devices your NIC is connected to has the power management checkbox active as well *(but this is going extra)*

---

*If not, try...*

Opening an elevated command prompt and run the following command:

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

if that doesn't help you can re-enable it with

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal
```

In case it may be related to [Windows Auto Tuning](https://www.duckware.com/blog/how-windows-is-killing-internet-download-speeds/index.html)

---

*If not, try...*

Instead of *updating* your drivers, try **rolling back** to an older driver. Some users on have reported encountering the same issue following the [1903](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-1903-update-capped-my-internet-speed/b034b04b-564b-492f-be27-7f1ee1f01b6a) or [1909](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-pro-link-speed-changing-on-its-own/36328441-6962-4ba9-918a-2a8083df0bd9?page=1&rtAction=1619529120553) Windows update.

---

*If not, try...*

Configuring the duplex setting using power shell instead in case there may be other policies in place that override the settings you set using the GUI...

Open a Powershell window and run the following command

```
Get-NetAdapter | SELECT name, LinkSpeed, fullduplex | ft -autosize
```

Take note of the adapter name as shown (although you mentioned "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" it might be just called "Ethernet" when running the powershell command) and under LinkSpeed, it probably wont say 1 Gbps if the error persists but may show something like 100 Mbps instead and if under the fullduplex column it shows True, then you can try running this command after:

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty $adaptername -DisplayName "Link Speed & Duplex" -DisplayValue "1000 Mbps Full Duplex"
```

Whereas you need to replace `$adaptername` with the name of the adapter as noted earlier.

If none of these help, the only thing left I can think of is to see if you can uninstall the update (though this applies more for other people since this post is so long ago Windows won't let you do this) or the specific update for your NIC if one is listed under installed updates from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Late and I think the issue is the cabling. Perhaps because I'm old enough to remember when it was a huge deal getting a CAT 5. Non e because they weren't available quite yet. Sorry for reminiscing, but I was surprised that nobody mentioned it. Maybe it's so we'll known it's a given, or maybe a long lost internet fact from the days of yore either way, CAT 5 cable tops out at 100Mbps. It looks very similar to CAT 5e but it can handle 1Gbps. Look closely at the insulation the type should be printed, dot matrix-style.

Comment: “bought new Cat6 cable, to rule out bad cable”, so not very likely.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is your whole issue, but if you change the setting "speed & Duplex" from AUTO on the NIC then you also have to change it on the switch port....otherwise when the connection is first made to the switch and the switch attempts to auto-negotiate the connection speed it will not get a response and then the switch will downgrade to the lowest setting (100 or 10 mb) to make sure it has a connection of some kind so if you were to look at an error log in the switch you would have a speed/duplex mismatch error.....we used to run into this a lot setting up VOIP phone networks. Cabling isn't an issue if the connectors are done correctly because I have seen CAT3 do 100mb connections....